# How to get the binary path for any package?

Tags: ros, catkin, path, binary, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

How do I get the binary path where the executables are stored for a specific package.
Need it for a console script.

Should work anywhere in devel and in install.

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212635/how-to-get-the-binary-path-for-any-package?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [Determine path to executable](http://answers.ros.org/question/209051/determine-path-to-executable/#209076).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-01**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-01**:
Np.

Btw: we don't normally close questions. Ticking the checkmark is enough to indicate that it was answered.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-01**:
Not I saw a recommendation to close topics recently on ros users mailing. Ok I will remember that.
Do you close it at all?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-01**:
David Lu suggested to close outdated questions. Answered questions should just be marked as such by ticking the checkmark.